# Après ou avec tout ce que j’ai fait pour toi, tu me laisses tomber?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

> Avec tout ce que j’ai fait pour toi, tu me laisses tomber, n’est-ce pas?

> Après tout ce que j’ai fait pour toi, tu me laisses tomber, n’est-ce pas?

Autres exemples prenant modèle sur les phrases précédentes.

> Avec tous les services que je t’ai rendus, tu n’as pas l’amabilité de m’en rendre ne serait-ce qu’un seul petit en retour? Ta décision me fait pitié!

> Après tous les services que je t’ai rendus, tu n’as pas l’amabilité de m’en rendre ne serait-ce qu’un seul en retour? Ta décision me fait pitié!

Une tournure plus courante (à la rigueur littéraire), s’il en existe une, serait bienvenue!

Merci

Comment: 1/ Les formes  « hors syntaxe » sans guillemets, c'est reconnu comme correct tout d'un coup ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Les deux sont courants dans cet usage ; il est cependant difficile de savoir quel est l'usage dominant. Si on se réfère aux définitions du TLFi on s'aperçoit néanmoins que seul « avec » convient sécifiquement ; il n'existe pas de définition correspondante pour « après ».

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/avec)) **3.** [Indique la présence simultanée d'éléments formant contraste, la restriction, l'oppos.] En dépit de, malgré.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/apr%C3%A8s)) après

On pourra consulter la page de résultats Google « [après tout ce que](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22apr%C3%A8s%20tout%20ce%20que%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) », et s'apercevoir que la présence d'éléments simultanés formant contraste est régulièrement vérifiable.

Il semble n'y  avoir réellement rien qui permette de dire laquelle de ces deux prépositions serait préférable.

*Littéraire, tout droit de la définition ci-dessus*

- Malgré tous les services que je t’ai rendus, tu n’as pas l’amabilité de m’en rendre ne serait-ce qu’un seul petit en retour? Ta décision me fait pitié! (*litt. et registre courant*)
- En dépit de  tous les services que je t’ai rendus, tu n’as pas l’amabilité de m’en rendre ne serait-ce qu’un seul petit en retour? Ta décision me fait pitié! (*litt. et registre pas très courant*)

*Autres possibilités, toujours littéraire*

- ([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Bulletin_de_la_Soci%C3%A9t%C3%A9_d_%C3%A9tudes_des_H/9n5NAAAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22au+m%C3%A9pris+de%22&dq=%22au+m%C3%A9pris+de%22&printsec=frontcover))  elle n'hésitât pas à joindre à son nom les épithètes de « mielleux » et de « subalterne » , au mépris de près de quinze ans d'une amitié qui paraissait sincère
- Au mépris de tout ce que j’ai fait pour toi, tu me laisses tomber, n’est-ce pas?